# How to convert Java 8 map.remove to Java 1.6?

Tags: java

I have the following:

```
     fruitMap.remove(fruitId, fruitProperties);
```

The fruitMap is:

```
private Map<FruitId, FruitProperties> fruitMap = new HashMap<FruitId, FruitProperties>();
```

When I attempt to build my code I get a:

```
ERROR
The method remove(Object) in the type Map<MyImplementation.FruitId, FruitProperties>
is not applicable for the arguments (Map<MyImplementation.FruitId, FruitProperties>)
```

What is the issue?

Note that thiis call is inside of a method "removeFruit()" inside my "FruitImplementation" class.

Comment: How is `fruitId` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `remove(key, value)` method removes the entry for `key` if it is currently mapped to `value`. The method was added in Java 1.8. The Javadoc for the `Map` interface mentions the following default implementation:

```
if (map.containsKey(key) && Objects.equals(map.get(key), value)) {
     map.put(key, newValue);
     return true;
} else
     return false;
```

Since the `Objects` class was only added in Java 1.7, for Java 1.6 you have to write the equality test yourself. So, if you don't need the return value of the method, you can replace `map.remove(key, value)` with:

```
if (map.containsKey(key) {
    Object storedValue = map.get(key);
    if (storedValue == null ? value == null : storedValue.equals(value)) {
        map.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Note that this is not thread-safe. If you access the map from multiple threads, you will have to add a synchronized block.

Answer (score 7):

From [the Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#remove-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object-):

> The default implementation is equivalent to, for this map:

```
if (map.containsKey(key) && Objects.equals(map.get(key), value)) {
     map.remove(key);
     return true;
 } else
     return false;
```

> The default implementation makes no guarantees about synchronization or atomicity properties of this method. Any implementation providing atomicity guarantees must override this method and document its concurrency properties.

So you could use that default implementation. Put it in a static helper method maybe.

But if this is supposed to be thread-safe, you may need to add some synchronization code (or consider using a ConcurrentMap, which by the way already has the remove method since Java 5).

Comment: Java 6 doesn't have the `Objects` class.

Comment: I think it has to be synchronized? How do you get around not having an Objects class? I am not sure if it has to or not, I want to preserve that style of code without breaking anything.

Comment: If you need synchronization, you may want to use a ConcurrentMap, which has the remove method even before Java8. (Note that the default implementation in Java8 is not synchronized either -- but will be for concurrent maps). Instead of Objects.equals, you can use `fruitProperties.equals` (assuming those can never be null).

Comment: @Rolando Your Java 8 code isn't thread safe, so If all you want to do is mimic the Java 8 code, you don't need to care about thread safety/synchronization The Java 8 documentation for Objects.equals describes what it does, so you can code it yourself. It's essentially `if (a == null && b == null) return true; if(a == null) return false; if (b == null) return false; return a.equals(b);`

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to test the value yourself:

```
if(fruitProperties.equals(fruitMap.get(fruitId)) {
    fruitMap.remove(fruitId);
}
```

Note, my implementation here assumes you are testing a non-null `fruitProperties` object.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do the following assuming your values cannot be `null`

```
if (fruitProperties.equals(fruitMap.get(fruitId))
    fruitMap.remove(fruitId);
```

Note: for this to be thread safe you would need to wrap this in a `synchronized` block.

Answer (score 1):

Here is complete solution, handling `synchronization` and specific cases like `null` values.

```
synchronized (fruitMap)
{
    if ((fruitMap.containsKey(fruitId) // The key is present
    && (
           (fruitProperties == null && fruitMap.get(fruitId) == null) // fruitProperties is null, so is the stored value
        || (fruitProperties != null && fruitProperties.equals(fruitMap.get(fruitId)))
       )
    )
    {
        fruitMap.remove(fruitId);
    }   
}
```

It works in Java 6, it's an equivalent to :

```
fruitMap.remove(fruitId, fruitProperties);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Objects.equals](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Objects.java#Objects.equals%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.lang.Object%29) has an implementation like this :

```
public static boolean equals(Object a, Object b) {
    return (a == b) || (a != null && a.equals(b));
}
```

Therefore, the default implementation of remove :

```
 if (map.containsKey(key) && Objects.equals(map.get(key), value)) {
     map.remove(key);
     return true;
 } else
     return false;
```

Can be written in Java 6 as :

```
if (map.containsKey(key) && ((map.get(key) == value) || (map.get(key) != null && map.get(key).equals(value)))) {
     map.remove(key);
     return true;
} else
     return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the Java Doc, remove(Object key, Object value)

> Removes the entry for the specified key only if it is currently mapped
>   to the specified value.

If your equals() is properly defined, you can do something like this

```
FruitProperties valueFromMap = map.get(key);
if(valueFromMap != null){
  if( valueFromMap == originalValue || valueFromMap.equals(originalValue)){
     map.remove(key);
  } 
}
```

Now that you're using simple HashMap, I assume that you'll take care of thread-safety by either synchronizing or change it to ConcurrentHashMap :)